# Lua's Table Equivalent In Python

Tags: python, lua, lua-table

Is there a python table equivalent to lua's?

```
-- Lua's Table
a = {}
a.x = 10
a.y = 10
print(a.x)
print(a.y)

-- OUTPUT
10
10
```

Comment: Please can can you expand on on your question, I don't understand what you are looking for

Comment: You are looking for [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). More [docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = {}
a["x"] = 10
a["y"] = 10
print(a["x"])
print(a["y"])

# OUTPUT
10
10
```

Is this what you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

```py
from typing import TypedDict, List


class Vec(TypedDict):
    x: int
    y: int

# You would typically use a custom validation function to ensure runtime integrity,
# but for static typing or IDE warnings this will work
# IDE will show a warning if you try to add **z**
a: Vec = {'x':1, 'y': 0, 'z': 0} # note I have added z here to show it will still work
print(a)

# OR simplest

a : Dict[str, int] = { "r": 1, "g": 255, "b": 255 }
```